# Converting huge ASCII file to flat and convert

Tags: database-recommendation, excel

I am not a db administrator but I thought to ask this question here.

I have several very large ASCII files (3-5GB each) that I need to extract the data and then sort it.  The instructions say to "extract the zip file into a flat file" and then to "create a program to convert that flat file to whatever application the client chooses to use".

I am not sure if this is something that is simple to do, or if I should hire a database pro to do this.  I am familiar with the basic workings of SQL but maybe enough to get into trouble.

So far I have used something called gVim to look at the files, but they are not delimited in any way except for spaces.

Could someone give me advice on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you contact the supplier of the files to confirm the delimiter? Using the SQL Server import process can help identify but knowing for sure what the delimiters are up front is a better idea. When you say sort the files what do you mean and what is the ultimate outcome of the data? if you just need to merge the files there are other options than SQL tools

Comment: Paste a few lines here - use the code sample option.

Answer (score 1):

When using a databse to sort the data one needs to know the structure of the data. In other words, there must be a field delimiter and a row delimiter. 
Then you can import the file into a SQL-table and index it and sort it the way you want. Importing flat files is easy done with tools provided by any Database Engine, for example SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) or MySQL LOAD.

Comment: Thank you I am trying to figure out what the delimiter is.  MattyZDBA's comment below says I might try Access to take a look at this.  Unfortunately, MS Access 2013 chokes on the smaller of the two files (1.8GB) and does not show anything.  Do you have any suggestions of an app that would show me what the delimiter is?

Answer (score 0):

One quick approach to figure out the structure and delimiters of your files would be to use a desktop application with a data import function. MS Excel works very well for smaller files but I find MS Access works very well for larger files and has the advantage of suggesting suitable data types that can port over to SQL Server later. You can toggle the delimiter options in both wizards to see how the file would be parsed.

One distant possibility is that the file is fixed width so that the values begin and end in specific column positions. For example, first name can be in the first 15 characters of a line while last name would be 15 characters starting in position #16 on a row. Because of the spaces you're seeing, the space may be the actual delimiter. Visual inspection would be the way to confirm this.

Comment: Thank you I am trying to import the smaller of the 2 files (1.8GB) into Access 2013 using the External Data -> Text File function, but Access hangs and throws an error after 20 minutes or so.  Excel does the same thing.  I only have 32-bit versions of each of these by the way.  Any other suggestions for initially opening this file up and seeing what the delimiters are?

Answer (score 0):

Matty, I use Notepad++ (free) for this purpose. It it is able to handle very big files by not loading all data in memory.  (Though I have to say that 1.8GB is big!) UltrEdit does the same job.

Another way is to use the Unix "head -n*N* [filename]" command which delivers you just the top *N* lines. For example: head -n 5 foo.txt , for the first 5 lines of file foo.txt.